# How can I escape "&" in XML?

Tags: xml

I write

```
 <string name="magazine">Newspaper & Magazines</string>
```

in file *strings.xml*.

But the compiler says:

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. strings.xml /OOReaderWidget/res/values line 9 Android XML Format Problem

How can I show a "&" in *strings.xml*?

Comment: XML and HTML are similar, but where is the corresponding canonical Stack Overflow question for HTML? (Many search engine hits end up here.)

Answer (score 542, accepted):

Use `&amp;` in place of `&`.

Change it to:

```
<string name="magazine">Newspaper &amp; Magazines</string>
```

Comment: Just in case anyone reaches this question the same i did, there is the list of escape characters in .xml files and how to escape them: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_xml_escape.html

Answer (score 104):

& → &amp;

< → &lt;

> → &gt;

Answer (score 13):

You can use `&amp;` in place of `&`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined%5Fentities%5Fin%5FXML