# How can I include an ampersand (&) character in an XML document?

Tags: xml, validation

How can I put an `&` symbol in an attribute of an XML tag while keeping the XML valid?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<a text="b&c"/>
```

When I use [W3School's validator](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp), I get the error:

> EntityRef: expecting '`;`'

Comment: Related post - [How to escape "&" in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12524908/465053)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use a character reference to represent it: `&amp;`

See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section.
>
> If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "
>                         `&amp;`
>                     " and "
>                         `&lt;`
>                     " respectively. The right angle bracket (>) may be represented using the string "
>                         `&gt;`
>                     ", and MUST, for compatibility, be escaped using either "
>                         `&gt;`
>                     " or a character reference when it appears in the string "
>                         `]]>`
>                     " in content, when that string is not marking the end of a CDATA section.

Comment: i like this answer better than other answers on other questions because it quotes the spec and i was able to escape all potential chars instead of just OP's one char

Answer (score 11):

You can use these escape sequences :

```
< (less-than)                   -   &#60; or &lt;

> (greater-than)                -   &#62; or  &gt;

& (ampersand)                   -   &#38;

' (apostrophe or single quote)  -   &#39;

" (double-quote)                -   &#34;
```

Comment: [Here's a link](https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html) to more reading on these escape sequences.

Answer (score 1):

```
Re: XML and ampersand in links - not parsing
You should escape & with 

> Blockquote &amp; in an XML or HTML document.
```