& within xml code is causing XSLT step to fail
I have a workday integration where xml output is transformed to csv using an XSLT code. The xml causing the issue is as follows: 10337,ACMC,20240601,ACD,000M&E. The error message says that 'The reference to entity "E" must end with the ';' delimiter'. Now what should I do to in the XSLT code so that it outputs '&' as is?
I tried adding the following to the XSLT code but I still got the same error: <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&', '&')"/>

10337,ACMC,20240601,ACD,000M&E is not valid xml. This is caused by &. Change it to &amp;.  See this answer for more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14500841/3710053

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

XSLT can only process well-formed XML. You need to correct the XML before you submit it to the XSLT processor.
