# Escape "&" ampersand

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am trying to print a currency symbol and am passing `&#x020AC;` for an euro to a third-party library that is doing some [XSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL) transformation.

But the output is: `&amp;#x020AC;`

It basically is translating `&` to `&amp;`. I cannot return the correct output.

Is there any way I can construct the input such that I get an output of "€"?

Comment: Take a look at [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp)

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. I recommend using the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead.

Comment: Thanks @James. However, the transformation is happening in the 3rd party library hence if I pass "<![CDATA[&#x020AC;]]>", the output I get is "&lt;![CDATA[&amp;#x020AC;]]&gt;" ... I wanted to know if my input can be formatted such a way that "&" is the putput and not "&nbsp;"

Comment: I think it would be helpful to know where you input the data. Please, provide more information and some code, otherwise all we can do is guessing.

Comment: Hi @CarloCannas, there is a 3rd party library say, FileCreator 
My code looks like the lines below; please note that i would not be able to massage the output; hence would need to format my input such a way that the & are not parsed as &amp;
FileCreator.setInput("<b>myInput<b>");
FileCreator.createFile("c:\myfile.html");

==Output==
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
  &lt;b&gt;myInput&lt;b&gt;
  </body>
</html>

Comment: @user3101143 unless you provide us the relevant code in order to reproduce the problem, we cannot help you. Also, don't provide it in the comments, edit the question.

Comment: Can you not pass € literally ? It looks liek your library is escaping for you

Comment: @NogginHead, you almost hit the bullseye .... I actually am generating an MS Excel file with the currencies and if you see the file I generated (http://tinyurl.com/currencytestxls), opening it in the text editor shows the correct symbol but somehow, MS Excel does not display the symbol. I am guessing there is some issue with the encoding.

Comment: On the surface, it looks as if the third party library has a bug. So you either have to get them to fix it, or stop using that library.

Comment: If you are coming from a search engine result just looking for how to escape "&" in HTML (e.g., using "escape ampersand HTML"), see e.g. [this answer to *How can I escape "&" in XML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-can-i-escape-in-xml/12524951#12524951) (they also apply to HTML, at least for "&"). What is the Stack Overflow canonical question for HTML only?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us what the library is, but I'm guessing that it just expects non-escaped Unicode... in which case, as [Noggin Heads said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751427/escape-ampersand#comment31098918_20751427), you should pass the € character in and trust the system to do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears to be escaping characters on its own, just type the character and see if it escapes.