# Create excel pivot table chart using EPPlus error with special character '&' in column name

Tags: c#, xml, excel, epplus, epplus-4

I am crating an excel file with pivot table and charts.
When I use '&' in column name it throws error "One or more errors occurred".
Error is only when creating pivot table.

```
var pivot1 = pivotSheetT1.PivotTables.Add(pivotSheetT1.Cells["A3"], Range, "some text");
```

How to handle characters like '&' ?
I do not ant to remove this character, I need to show it in excel file.

Comment: Just a wild guess - can you try with "&amp;" and see what happens ?
This will use the Xml escape sequence for "&"  (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-to-escape-in-xml)

Comment: Replacing & with &amp; excel is generated but corrupted excel.