# Java DOM: getElementsByTagName is returning no elements?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I am trying to parse the XML document at http://web.mta.info/status/ServiceStatusSubway.xml and extract all the `PtSituationElement` elements with the following code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document subwayStatusDoc = builder.parse(new URL("http://web.mta.info/status/ServiceStatusSubway.xml").openStream());

NodeList situationList = subwayStatusDoc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("PtSituationElement");
System.out.println(situationList.item(0)); //prints null
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PtSituationElement tags contain child tags, so you need to go into those. Just printing .item(0) relies on the toString() method, and apparently it does not do a great job of explaining your nodes.

So add this to see some of the data in the child nodes:

```
    Node item = situationList.item(0);
    NodeList childNodes = item.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
        System.out.println(childNodes.item(j).getTextContent());
    }
```

(I'm not sure what you want to do with the data in the xml structure, but this example shows how you can proceed with your work.)

Also, I noted that the LongDescription tags contain HTML that is not correct XML (`<br clear=left>` should be `<br clear=left>` etc). The parser could have a problem with that. It would be better if the HTML was escaped (see [How to escape "&" in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-to-escape-in-xml)).