# Adding ampersand in liquibase default value field

Tags: liquibase, ampersand

I need add a default value for a column in liquibase changeset.

```
<changeSet id="1">
        <insert tableName="table_name">
            <column name="column_name" value="value1 & value2"/>
        </insert>
</changeSet>
```

Since liquibase treats ampersand '&' as special character, it marks it as an error. What is the escape character for & in liquibase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Realised the escape character would be same as the one used in any other XML based document since liquibase is XML based.

i.e the escape character is `&amp;`

Reference - [stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-to-escape-in-xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524908/how-to-escape-in-xml)

P.S answering my own question but feel it would be useful for others looking for the same info.