# How to insert & ampersand character into database using liquibase

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I am trying to insert the string "& n b s p;" (without spaces) into Oracle db using liquibase.
& is special character in xml, so I need to escape it somehow.
I tried

```
<insert tableName="XY">
  <column name="foo" type="string"  value="&amp;nbsp;"/>
</insert>
```

But I am getting:

> Error parsing line *xx* column *yy* of bar.xml: The entity nbsp was referenced, but not declared

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64422392/adding-ampersand-in-liquibase-default-value-field (however, you're already using `&amp;` which that answer says is the solution...)